# dismissKeyboard - unrecognized selector

Tags: ios, xcode, swift4

In some View Controller I have the following commands:

```
    //Looks for single or multiple taps.
    let tap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(LoginVC.dismissKeyboard))


    //add tap gesture
    view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
```

but after changing language from swift3 to swift4 I have started receiving the following error

**[iosapp_v147.ChangePasswordViewController dismissKeyboard]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x155e04090**

Any help rendered will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is indicating that the target object (a `ChangePasswordViewController`) receiving the `dismissKeyboard` call has no function declared as `@objc dismissKeyboard()`

Make sure that `ChangePasswordViewController` has a `dismissKeyboard` function declared with the `@objc` attribute. That's required for all `#selector` references.

You should also be able to declare the selector without the `"LoginVC."` prefix, since the your target is self.

```
let tap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(dismissKeyboard))
```

Finally, make sure the function signature has no labels (`dismissKeyboard(this:that:)`).

If it's none of those things, post the function declaration.